# find words that match user input with strstr

Tags: arrays, c, struct, strstr

In my register, I want to find all the words that match user input and display them.

For example if I have words like redapple, rottenapple, apple, banana in my register.

And user inputs apple I want to be able to dispaly redapple, rottenapple, apple  and their itemnumber and inventory balance. I cannot display in the right way and cannot figure it why, have tried different way and I will post my last try. Thank you!

```
void search(Car a[],int nr){

    char ItmName[50];

    int i;
    while(1){
       
        printf("Type item name (q for menu): ");
        scanf("%s%*c", &ItmName);
   
        if(strcmp(ItmName,"q")==0){
            return;
        }else{
            for(i=0;i<nr;i++){
               char *word = strstr(a[i].name,ItmName);
                 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
                   if(word==itemN){
                   printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", a[i].itemNmr, a[i].name, a[i].inventory);
            }
            return;
        }
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Belaying the warning you should be getting from `scanf("%s%*c", &ItmName)` (which should be `scanf("%s%*c", ItmName)`), there is no `itemN` defined in this code. And even if there were, `if(word==itemN)` would be comparing a pointer against it, not content-pointed-to. You clearly know how to compare strings; you did so with `if(strcmp(ItmName,"q") == 0)`, so why aren't you doing that?

Comment: I meant itemName, but since it is worng I guess it deos not matter. Do you mena that I should have strcmp if((word,reg[i].name)==0) I tried it and if i search for apple it only gives me one result apple and its balance. I even tried  if((word,ItmName)==0)  and it did not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop use the same control variable, `i`, and continuation condition, which ensures only one iteration of the outer loop occurs.

The contents of the loop make little sense. You repeatedly compare a pointer to the first element of the input buffer (`itemN`; pressumably `itemName`) against the pointer value returned by `strstr`, after it looks through the name field of only the *first* element of the `a` array for the substring provided in `itemName`.

Rewritten verbosely, this reads as

```
for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        if (strstr(a[0].name, itemName) == &itemName[0]) {
            printf(/* some information */);
        }
    }
}
```

which hopefully you can see makes no sense. A pointer value that points to an element of `a[0].name` will never be equal to the pointer value that points to the first element of `itemName` - as that would require their memory to overlap somehow.

---

In any case, this should not require any nested loops, as this can be done with a linear search of your array of structures.

First suggestion: move the user input to outside the function. Make `search` accept a third argument, a string to search for in each structures name. Separately (and repeatedly) take user input and then call this function.

Second suggestion: forget `scanf` exists entirely. Use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (and `sscanf` if you need to extract formatted data from the string).

Here's a cursory example of a linear search function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[128];
    unsigned inventory;
} Car;

void search(Car *cars, size_t length, const char *query)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (strstr(cars[i].name, query))
            printf("NAME: [%s]\tQUANT: [%u]\n", cars[i].name, cars[i].inventory);
}

int main(void)
{
    Car cars[] = {
        { "redapple", 10 },
        { "rottenapple", 7 },
        { "foo", 4 },
        { "bar", 15 },
        { "candyapple", 11 }
    };

    size_t len = sizeof cars / sizeof *cars;

    while (1) {
        char buf[512];

        printf("Enter a search string (. = exit): ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            return 1;

        if ('.' == *buf)
            return 0;

        /* remove any trailing CRLF */
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = '\0';

        search(cars, len, buf);
    }
}
```